# How to make tableViewCell Vertical Paging like a carousel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, infinite-scroll

Currently tableview cells look like this: [current cell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PCUA.jpg) When my app first opens it looks like the picture on the left and when I scroll one page down it looks like the picture on the right.

However I want it to look like a carousel: [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKoiS.png)

I want it so when it I scroll (paging enabled) the bottom cell comes to middle cell spot, and the new bottom cell is at the old bottom cell spot, and the middle cell is at the top cell spot.

Possible Solutions/Questions:

How would I make the UITableViewCells infinitely loop, and thus start off with the ability to scroll up and down, since the last cell would be above the first cell to begin with. Right now there is no cell above the first one, which poses a problem.

CODE:

```
 func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {


        targetContentOffset.pointee.y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y + 100
    }
```

I want to basically snap the bottom card/ top card that is swiping to the middle of the screen.

Comment: you probably want to look at UIPageViewController or a UICollectionView rather than a UITableView, You can't change the scroll direction on a tableview

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Can you share your code on where you got stuck? I think we need some more info.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel If you don't use it entirely you can at least see how they implemented this type of paging

Comment: I was trying to do a vertical paging carsouel, rather then a horizontal one? Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: Hey , I added the code.

Comment: Have you tried using `func scrollToRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, at scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)`? You can specifie `middle` as scroll position, and then you won't have to calculate the offsets yourself.